# Sharepoint site column

Tags: site-column

I'm new to sharepoint and have been tasked with converting a regular (php) website into sharepoint.

I've been struggling with one thing at the moment....

I want to create more than one editable region on a pagelayout page.

using Sharepoint desinger I dragged over a Page Content field from the toolbar and this works great. However if I drag another one on to the page, they both share the same content.

So.... I created another column and made it a full html field. It appears in my toolbar and I can drag it onto my page - however when I go into edit mode on the actual browser - it does not show an editing box.

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks,

KS

Answer (score 1):

Have you dragged your new column into an EditModePanel with it's DisplayMode set to "Display" rather than "Edit"?